# Is there a way to get a list of the files that were generated, from a large table, when exporting from BigQuery to GCS using a wildcard option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I used the wildcard * export in order to export a large BigQuery table into separate files in GCS. I used the code sample provided in GCP's docs:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = 'bucket'
project = "project"
dataset_id = "dataset"
table_id = "table"


destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "table*.parquet")
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="US",
)  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```

This generated 19 different files in my storage bucket like this `mytable000000000000.parquet` and `mytable000000000001.parquet` and so on (up to 0000000000019).

It would be nice to have an automatic way to get a list of these file names so that I can either `compose` them together or loop over them to do something else. Is there an easy way to edit the code above to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get an explicit list when using a wildcard, but take a look at the `destinationUriFileCounts` field in the [extract job statistics](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobStatistics4).  It would tell you how many files are present.  In python, this is available [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.ExtractJob.destination_uri_file_counts).

If you want stronger validation, you could also leverage the Cloud Storage libraries and list objects with the same pattern(s) you supplied as part of the extract configuration.